# Is it possible to test whether a number is prime or not in O(logn)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, number-theory, primality-test

I have been reading a competitive programming book for one month. The book is written by one of the world finalists of our country (Bangladesh). Point to be noted, the book is written in our native language (Bengali) and that is not so popular worldwide. Because of having the content in Bengali I can't refer it here. That's why I am sorry first of all.

In Number theory chapter of that book, there are given many algorithms to test Primality. The most optimal he has shown, is "Sieve of Eratosthenes" in O(nloglogn). But he wrote one line. I am translating it.
"There is a more efficient method of testing primality in O(logn). Think it yourself. And if you are undone, just google it!!"

I have googled about it.But I didn't find anything satisfactory.

Is it really possible to test the primality of a number in O(logn) ??
 And if it is possible then up to which range it can be concluded ??

Comment: He probably means that once the sieve has been pre-computed, you can test for primality in O(logn). The method has been discussed [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-factorization-using-sieve-olog-n-multiple-queries/).

Comment: What you gave  is not about primality test but prime factorization. @VishnuDasu

Comment: You can easily modify the code to determine whether the number is prime or not. One simple way is to just count the number of factors. Complexity would still be O(logn). @KaziZiaulHassan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement is incorrect. For a number N, the number of digits is `O(log N)`, so the statement means that there is an algorithm that's *linear* in the number of digits. The best known result is polynomial in the number of digits. (Agrawal–Kayal–Saxena primality test, Õ(logN <sup>12</sup>). That's logN to the power of twelve, not one.

Still, Õ(logN <sup>12</sup>) ⊂ O(N)

Comment: I've never seen the symbol Õ. What does this mean?

Comment: And even for probabilistic algorithms it would be at least Õ(k*log N^2^).

Comment: @0x499602D2: Ignoring factors of O(log(log(N))).

Comment: @0x499602D2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Extensions_to_the_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Book author is correct you can do primality test of a number n which is large in 0(logn) using **Miller-Rabin primality test for large numbers**. You can search this test on google to know more.

Comment: It's O(log^3(n)) for crypto-sized numbers. [Miller-Rabin complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Complexity).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This conjecture is actually wrong, I was too excited that I put it here. My bad.

There's a conjecture on https://oeis.org/A000040 that gives a primality test in O(logn) using Fibonacci numbers. It states that for n > 5, n is prime if and only if  (Fibonacci(n) mod n = 1 or Fibonacci(n) mod n = n - 1) and 2^(n-1) mod n = 1. The n'th Fibonacci number can be calculated in O(logn) using matrix exponentiation, and 2^(n-1) can be calculated in O(logn) using binary exponentiation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).